# Awkward conflict between lastpage, hyperref, amsthm and tikz-external

Tags: hyperref, incompatibility, amsthm, tikz-external, lastpage

The following code cannot correctly produce the external .pdf file of the tikzpicture. Removing any of `\usepackage{amsthm}`, `\usepackage{lastpage}`, `\usepackage{hyperref}` solves the issue: the auxiliary .pdf file is correctly produced. Removing `\tikzexternalize` also solves the problem, because no externalization process is involved.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) --(1,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The .log file of the external compilation contains the following

```
! Argument of \Hy@temp has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.62 \end{document}
```

I've also tried to swap the order of the packages, with no result. What can be causing this problem?

Comment: I put hyperref last and got no errors (other than never having gotten \tikzexternalize to work on my system).

Comment: What's the exact order you used? I can't make it work :(

Comment: I just moved hypperref after \tikzexternalize.  BTW, of the packages used \Hy@temp only shows up in hyperref (of course) and lastpage.

Comment: I can't make it work... Are you sure you deleted the previously created external .pdf? If a previous compilation successfully created the file, then the next compilations will re-use it without trying to generate it again.

Comment: I would like to use externalize to speed up compilation of large documents with lots of tikzpictures. But at the moment it isn't compiling, so I'm dropping the externalization until I find a fix.

Comment: I use standalone and \includegraphics instead.  Externalize will never be any faster, just more convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some packages are just incompatible with externalization, see section 50.8.2 in the TikZ/PGF manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\tikzifexternalizing{}{
  \usepackage{lastpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) --(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't control whats included, you could issue `\usepackage{cleveref}` to fix it miraculously, as suggested here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538748/why-does-usepackagecleveref-fix-the-conflict-between-new-hyperref-amsthm

Comment: `\usepackage{cleveref}` --> I do not know why it works, but it works.